# Is there a quicker way to do this in GAP?

Tags: group-theory, gap, group-presentation

*If this isn't clear, I'm sorry.*

I'm investigating what groups one gets using a certain procedure.

Take a group $H$. Let $w=x_ex_mx_k^{-1}$ be an element of the free group on $X:=\{x_h\mid h\in H\}$ for $m,k\in H\setminus\{e\}$ with $m\neq k$ and $e$ the identity of $H$. I'm looking at the groups given by the presentation $$G_H(w):=\langle X\mid \{x_hx_{hm}x_{hk}^{-1}\mid h\in H\}\rangle.$$ (They generalise the Fibonacci groups.)

---

For instance, for $H=C_2\times C_2=\{e,a,b,ab\}$ and $w=x_ex_ax_b^{-1}$, $G_H(w)=C_3$.

---

There are $7P2=42$ choices for $w=x_ex_mx_k^{-1}$ (not controlling for substitutions in $w$) when $H=C_2\times C_4=\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^4, ab=ba\rangle$. In GAP, for $w=x_ex_ax_b^{-1}$, I use

```
F:=FreeGroup("e","a","r","s","t","x","y","z");

rels:=ParseRelators(F,"ea=r,ae=x,rx=s,sy=t,tz=e,xr=y,ys=z,zt=a");

g:=F/rels;

iso:=IsomorphismSimplifiedFpGroup(g);

h:=Image(iso);

Print(RelatorsOfFpGroup(h));
```

with `e`$=x_e$, `a`$=x_a$, `r`$=x_b$, etc., and I'm calculating & changing the relations manually for each $w$.

> Is there a quicker way of doing this (that can be generalised to any group $H$)?

Please help :)

---

As requested in the comments, here's a full presentation of $G_H(w)$ for $H=C_2\times C_4=\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^4, ab=ba\rangle$ (with identity $e$) and $w=x_ex_ax_b^{-1}$ in terms of the $(x_h)_{h\in H}$:

$$G_H(w)=\langle \{x_h\mid h\in H\}\mid x_ex_a=x_b, x_ax_e=x_{ab}, x_{b}x_{ab}=x_{b^2}, x_{b^2}x_{ab^2}=x_{b^3}, x_{b^3}x_{ab^3}=x_e, x_{ab}x_b=x_{ab^2}, x_{ab^2}x_{b^2}=x_{ab^3}, x_{ab^3}x_{b^3}=x_a\rangle.$$

Comment: A few substitutions in $w$ reduce the number of groups given by this method. For instance, $y_g=x_{g^{-1}}^{-1}$.

Comment: The dependence of $G_H(w)$ on $w$ is not particularly clear. It looks as though it is a function of the group elements $m$ and $k$, so why not call it $G_H(m,k)$?

Comment: That's a useful observation, @DerekHolt. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to write yourself a function that forms such a list. For example, let

```
RelatorTriples:=function(f,p,q)
local gens,n,rels,i,redu;
  gens:=GeneratorsOfGroup(f);
  n:=Length(gens);
  redu:=x->((x-1) mod n)+1; # cyclic counting
  rels:=[];
  for i in [1..n] do
    Add(rels,gens[i]*gens[redu(AbsInt(p(i)))]^SignInt(p(i))
                    *gens[redu(AbsInt(q(i)))]^SignInt(q(i)));
  od;
  return rels;
end;
```

This function takes as argument a free group and two functions that calculate the values $p(i)$ and $q(i)$ in a triple $x_i*x_{p(i)}*x_{q(i)}$ with negative values denoting inverses.  For example

```
gap> H:=AbelianGroup(IsFpGroup,[2,4]);
<fp group of size 8 on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> SetReducedMultiplication(H); # enforce nice normal form of words
gap> e:=Elements(H);
[ <identity ...>, f1, f2, f1*f2, f2^2, f1*f2^2, f2^3, f1*f2^3 ]
```

Now create an appropriate free group (with generators named after the elements of $H$) and choose the parameters $m$ and $k$ of the example:

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup(List(e,x->Concatenation("x_",String(x))));
<free group on the generators [ x_<identity ...>, x_f1, x_f2, x_f1*f2, x_f2^2, x_f1*f2^2, x_f2^3, x_f1*f2^3 ]>
gap> m:=e[2];k:=e[3];
f1
f2
```

Now construct functiuons $p$ and $q$ which for generator $h$ (well, the number of generator $h$) return the number of the generator $hm$ and $q$ ditto:

```
gap> p:=x->Position(e,e[x]*m);;
gap> q:=x->-Position(e,e[x]*k);; # the - indicates inverse.
```

Then

```
gap> RelatorTriples(f,p,q);
```

returns the list

```
[ x_<identity ...>*x_f1*x_f2^-1, x_f1*x_<identity ...>*x_f1*f2^-1,
 x_f2*x_f1*f2*x_f2^2^-1, x_f1*f2*x_f2*x_f1*f2^2^-1,
 x_f2^2*x_f1*f2^2*x_f2^3^-1, x_f1*f2^2*x_f2^2*x_f1*f2^3^-1,
 x_f2^3*x_f1*f2^3*x_<identity ...>^-1, x_f1*f2^3*x_f2^3*x_f1^-1 ]
```

which at first glance looks like yours.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem: it translates calculating the relations to calculating $p$ and $q$, which doesn't seem any easier, since I'd have to know the relations to get them, right?

Comment: Your multiplication formula gives you $p$ and $q$. I might be misunderstanding your example. Can you write out the full presentation in your example, using only the four generators $x_h$ for $h\in H$ and not dropping generators (such as $b$) or introducing new ones (such as $t$) for which is is not clear to me what they are?

Comment: I've updated the question to include a full presentation.

Comment: @Shaun  Answer is updated.